# How to possible uitableviewcell swipe left and right without any button

Tags: ios

I want to be able to swipe left or right anywhere in a table view cell to erase the cell of with animation without showing the delete button. How can I do this?
see my use this code swipe cell left and right but right to left swipe is not perfectly https://github.com/Dromaguirre/DRCellSlideGestureRecognizer

Comment: Add a swipe gesture recognizer, get the coordinates of where the swipe occurred, get the cell at that views coordinates, call the table view's delete row at the cell's index path and pass an animation to fade left/right.